# Is there a V-lookup effect in Microsoft Access?

Tags: forms, ms-access

I am a novice self-teaching Microsoft Access.

I have an MS Access database with a table of students (Table1).

**Table1**

```
+----+-----------+----------+------------+------------+
| id | firstname | lastname | Year_Group | Form_Group |
+----+-----------+----------+------------+------------+
|  2 | mnb       | nbgfv    |          7 |          1 |
|  3 | jhg       | uhgf     |          8 |          2 |
|  4 | poi       | ijuy     |          9 |          2 |
|  5 | tgf       | tgfd     |         10 |          2 |
|  6 | wer       | qwes     |         11 |          2 |
+----+-----------+----------+------------+------------+
```

Every day students days are recorded sort of like Table2.

**Table2**

```
+----------+----+-----------+----------+------------+--------+-----------+----------+
|   Date   | id | firstname | lastname | Year_Group | Effort | Behaviour | Homework |
+----------+----+-----------+----------+------------+--------+-----------+----------+
| 28/02/19 |  2 | mnb       | nbgfv    |          7 | Good   | Good      | Y        |
| 28/02/19 |  3 | jhg       | uhgf     |          8 | OK     | OK        | Y        |
| 28/02/19 |  4 | poi       | ijuy     |          9 | Bad    | Bad       | N        |
| 01/03/19 |  5 | tgf       | tgfd     |         10 | Good   | OK        | Y        |
| 01/03/19 |  6 | wer       | qwes     |         11 | Good   | Good      | Y        |
+----------+----+-----------+----------+------------+--------+-----------+----------+
```

Is there a way (when using a list box or combo box) to select a student from Table1 so that their information is used for the corresponding columns in Table2?

Or is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Why revert the table formatting edit?

Comment: Haven't made a table on StackOverflow before, so it took me a few tries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you should **[normalise your data](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/283878/description-of-the-database-normalization-basics)**.

Currently, you are repeating the `firstname`, `lastname`, and `Year_Group` data in two separate tables, which not only bloats your database, but also means that such data must be maintained in two separate places, potentially leading to inconsistencies and then uncertainty as to which is the master.

Instead, I would suggest that your `Students` table should contain all information pertaining to the characteristics of a student:

**Students**

```
+----+-----------+----------+------------+------------+
| id | firstname | lastname | Year_Group | Form_Group |
+----+-----------+----------+------------+------------+
|  2 | mnb       | nbgfv    |          7 |          1 |
|  3 | jhg       | uhgf     |          8 |          2 |
|  4 | poi       | ijuy     |          9 |          2 |
|  5 | tgf       | tgfd     |         10 |          2 |
|  6 | wer       | qwes     |         11 |          2 |
+----+-----------+----------+------------+------------+
```

And the information pertaining to each school day should only reference the student ID in the `Students` table:

**SchoolDays**

```
+----------+----+--------+-----------+----------+
|   Date   | id | Effort | Behaviour | Homework |
+----------+----+--------+-----------+----------+
| 28/02/19 |  2 | Good   | Good      | Y        |
| 28/02/19 |  3 | OK     | OK        | Y        |
| 28/02/19 |  4 | Bad    | Bad       | N        |
| 01/03/19 |  5 | Good   | OK        | Y        |
| 01/03/19 |  6 | Good   | Good      | Y        |
+----------+----+--------+-----------+----------+
```

Then, if you want to display the data in its entirety, you would use a query which joins the two tables, e.g.:

```sql
select  
    t2.date,
    t1.firstname,
    t1.lastname, 
    t1.year_group, 
    t2.effort, 
    t2.behaviour, 
    t2.homework
from 
    students t1 inner join schooldays t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: And then use form/subform arrangement for data entry/edit or a single form bound to SchoolDays table with combobox to select student. Textboxes can reference columns of combobox to display student info but not to edit it.